# Switching between sender and receiver in Android Wi-Fi Direct app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, p2p, wifi-direct

I am developing an Android app to share files using Wi-Fi Direct. The app works, but I am unable to switch between being a sender and a receiver without closing the app. When I try to switch roles, the group owner is not updated and remains the same as the previous transfer. How can I update the group owner and switch roles correctly?

I do disconnect and reinitialize after every file transfer session. But it doesn't create a new group.

Here is my initialization code:

```
manager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE) as WifiP2pManager?
channel = manager?.initialize(this, mainLooper, null)?.also {
     receiver = P2pBroadcastReceiver(this)
}
```

And here is the code for connecting to a peer and switching roles:

```
fun connectToPeer(device: WifiP2pDevice, isSender: Boolean) {
    val config = WifiP2pConfig().apply {
        deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress
        groupOwnerIntent = if (isSender) WifiP2pConfig.GROUP_OWNER_INTENT_MIN else WifiP2pConfig.GROUP_OWNER_INTENT_MAX
    }
        
    channel?.also { channel ->
        manager?.connect(channel, config, object : WifiP2pManager.ActionListener {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                context.apply {
                    toast("${getString(R.string.connecting_to)} ${device.deviceName}")
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(reasonCode: Int) = onP2POperationFailed(reasonCode)
        })
    }
}
```

And here is the code for disconnecting from the group:

```
fun disconnect() {
    manager?.apply {
        cancelConnect(channel, null)
        removeGroup(channel, null)
        stopPeerDiscovery(channel, null)
        deletePersistentGroups()
    }
    try {
        if (::serverSocket.isInitialized) serverSocket.close()
        if (::clientSocket.isInitialized) clientSocket.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {}
}

private fun deletePersistentGroups() {
    try {
        val methods = WifiP2pManager::class.java.methods
        for (method in methods) {
            if (method.name == "deletePersistentGroup") {
                for (networkId in 0..31) {
                    method.invoke(manager, channel, networkId, null)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I would like for devices d1 and d2 to have the ability to switch roles without closing the app. Currently, d1 is set up to receive files and d2 is set up to send them. However, if d1 needs to send files without closing the app after d2 has finished sending its files, I would like for them to be able to easily reestablish the connection and initiate the transfer.

**Edit 2:**

How I initiate the file transferring or sending process:

```
private fun onConnectionInfoChanged(info: WifiP2pInfo?) {
    if (isDeviceConnected) {
        if (info!!.isGroupOwner) { // receiver || server || group owner
            startReceiverServer()
        } else { // sender || client
            startSenderClient(info.groupOwnerAddress)
        }
    }
}

private fun startReceiverServer() {
    runOnBg {
        serverSocket = ServerSocket(P2pFileTransferHelper.PORT)
        P2pFileTransferHelper.receiveFiles(serverSocket, context.contentResolver) { fileTransferInfoLiveData.postValue(it) }
    }
}

private fun startSenderClient(serverAddress: InetAddress) {
    runOnBg {
        clientSocket = Socket()
        P2pFileTransferHelper.sendFiles(clientSocket, serverAddress, selectedFilePaths) { fileTransferInfoLiveData.postValue(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Being a receiver or sender does not depend on being group owner or not. Both can send an receive. They can communicate. So i do not understand why you would change groupowner or else. Well just my thoughts.

Comment: I was following this documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct). Here, files are transferred by using Socket.

After the device connection, only the group owner's address is available on both devices, so I make that a receiver so that the sender can create a Socket object and send the files to that address.

I have added a few more codes, please check. And if you know of any other approach I can follow, please let me know.

Comment: A server socket can send and receive data. A client socket can send and receive data. Dont say: i make that one a receiver as both socket types can send and receive. You only can say: i make that one the server and that one the client.

Comment: Right. I wasn't aware of this. I thought one has to be the sender and the other one has to be the receiver. I'm able to fix it now. Thanks for the help .

Comment: I dont know what you want to achieve, but even if you solve it, wi-fi direct is not stable across different android devices, I would suggest using Wi-Fi hotspot or Wi-Fi router, keep in mind android devices have a limit on how many devices can connect to their hotspot at same time